# Solve the Laplace Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the Neumann problem:

$$U_{xx} + U_{yy} = 0, \qquad 0 < x < \pi, \quad -1< y < 1$$
with

$$U_x(0,y) = U_x(\pi,y) = 0$$
$$U_y(x,-1) = 0$$
$$ U_y(x,1) = \alpha + \beta \sin(x)$$

Does the problem admit solutions for the following?

1. $\alpha = 0, \beta = 1$
2. $\alpha = -1, \beta = \frac{\pi}{2}$
3. $\alpha = 1, \beta = \frac{\pi}{2}$
4. $\alpha = 1, \beta = -\pi$

Comment: Does my edit ask the right question? Also, what have you tried, where are you stuck, ...?

Comment: For PDEs, it is always important to specify what you mean by solutions. Are you trying to find classical solutions (in the sense that $U\in \mathcal{C}^2([0,\pi]\times [-1,1])$) or weak solutions (in the sens of distributions)?

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the problem must satisfy $$\oint \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} ds=0 $$ where the integral is taken over the boundary of the domain. This reduces to $$\int_0^\pi \left( \alpha+\beta \sin x \right) \mathrm{d}x=0.  $$

Comment: sir, I am not familiar with this result, I would be thanful for give me explanation of this result.Please explain this

Comment: It follows from [Green's first identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_identities#Green.27s_first_identity) applied to the functions $\phi=u,\psi=1$. The notations are a bit different, but in any case $\mathbf{n} \cdot \nabla \phi$ means the derivative with respect to the outwards pointing normal vector.